# Adding Meta Tags Dynamically - Angular

Tags: angular, seo, angular7, angular-universal

I am integrating Angular Universal in my Angular 7 app.

**1st way** (On production right now): 
My (all individual) blogs are published as separate `html` files, uploaded directly to S3 bucket (for SEO purposes), which includes `title`, `description` and meta-tags.

**2nd way** (development phase): 
Now I am integrating Angular Universal, what I am doing is that I am serving individual blogs from angular routes like `<url>/view-blog/{id}`. I am adding `title` and meta-tags using [`MetaService`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-meta/core#set-meta-tags-programmatically) like below

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    let blogId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (AppUtils.isUndefinedOrNull(blogId)) {
      // Return back to main blog page
      this.router.navigate([constants.pageUrl.blogs]);
      return;
    }

    this.loading = this.blogService.getBlogById(blogId).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        this.blog = resp.blog;

        this.metaService.setTitle(this.blog.title, true);
        this.metaService.setTag("keywords", this.blog.metadataKeywords);
        this.metaService.setTag("description", this.blog.name);

      }, (err) => {
        // Deal with error
      }

    )
  }
```

Using above code, we are waiting for service to return meta-tags, will Angular-Universal and [`MetaService`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-meta/core#set-meta-tags-programmatically) help crawler to find meta-tags ?

Also is "2nd way" right way to show blogs (keeping in mind that title, description, keywords and all SEO stuff set for crawlers) ? Or just stick to "1st way" ? What's the best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

I can not recommend you to use the second way. Most of crawlers do not execute JavaScript code, so they will never get know what the title was. Try to hardcode all important info for crawlers in HTML.